# Issues converting subquery to join

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table for a timeclock, and a table containing adjustments to the timeclock if an employee forgot to clock in/out. The format of the timeclock (newclock) table is like this -

id

datetime

event (IN or OUT)

employee_id

employer

The adjustment table (adjust_clock) is like this -

adjusted_shift (the ID of the shift being adjusted from the newclock table)

new_dt

I've got this query -

```
SELECT 
    nc.id AS clockInId,nc.pin, nc.employee_id,(
        SELECT min(newclock.id) 
        FROM newclock 
        WHERE 
            newclock.id > clockInId AND
            employee_id=nc.employee_id AND event='OUT'
    ) AS clockOutId,
    IFNULL(ac.new_dt, nc.tod) as clockInTime,
    IFNULL(
        (
            SELECT new_dt FROM adjust_clock WHERE adjusted_shift=clockOutId
            ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
        ), (
            SELECT tod FROM newclock WHERE
            newclock.id=clockOutId
        )
    ) AS clockOutTime
FROM newclock nc
LEFT JOIN 
    adjust_clock ac ON ac.adjusted_shift=nc.id
WHERE 
    nc.employer='122' AND (nc.tod) BETWEEN '2015-12-28 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-03 23:59:59'
    AND nc.event='IN'`
```

Everything works, it's just way too slow. Can anyone suggest a way to speed this up? The line that's killing performance is this - 

    `IFNULL((SELECT new_dt FROM adjust_clock WHERE adjusted_shift=clockOutId
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),(SELECT tod FROM newclock WHERE
    newclock.id=clockOutId)) AS clockOutTime`

I've tried putting it in a join like this, but no luck - 

    `LEFT JOIN (SELECT new_dt, adjusted_shift FROM adjust_clock ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1) adjustClockOut ON adjustClockOut.adjusted_shift=(SELECT
    min(newclock.id) FROM newclock WHERE newclock.id>nc.id AND nc.event='OUT' 
    AND newclock.employee_id=nc.employee_id)`

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you must keep this structure, a simple way to help performance would be verifying that you have your columns indexed properly. Specifically the columns that you are making comparisons/lookups on...